# Use of property in a class

Tags: python, class, properties

I have trouble understanding this code,

```
class Price:
    def __init__(self, price):
    self.price = price

    @property
    def price(self):
        return self.__price

   @price.setter
   def price(self, price):
        if price < 0:
            raise ValueError("Price cannot be negative")
        self.__price = price


pc = Price(500)
pc.price = -100
print(pc.price)
```

When we use the property object, does it mean that the method under the @property decorator will always be executed first and followed by the method under the @price.setter decorator? Or is it the other way around. Can someone explain the use of property in detail? I read some online explanation, but I am still confused.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The use of property is to allow for some code executions when trying to get/set/delete attribute. You example is good - without `property.setter`, user of our code could easily assign -100 to instance of `Price`.

But we don't want to have less-than-zero price... So we need to describe `price` as property, and add some logic to it. Then `property` code is used every time when accessing `Price().price` (getting `price`), or trying to set `.price` (`price setter`).